# Changing parameters in "a" element

Tags: function

I'm trying to change:

```
<a href="www.example.com">
```

by this:

```
<a onclick="parent.location='www.example.com'">
```

And I want to do this dynamically, I mean, with all the links in my site.
I don't know how to do this in functions.php

Obviously "www.example.com" is not a constant.

Can some of you help me? Thanks.

Comment: Do you want to hard code this into your markup (and block search engines from crawling your site) or change it per JavaScript dynamically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this pretty easily using jQuery.

First, strip off the `href` attribute and add the `onclick` attribute:

```
$('a').each(function() {
    $(this).attr('onclick', 'parent.location=\'' + $(this).attr('href') + '\'').removeAttr('href');
});
```